# cant setTag with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragment

How could i `setTag` for a `Fragment` when using `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Any suggestion

```
public class MainFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
 public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                SettingsFragment fr = new SettingsFragment();
```

<strike>fr.setTag();</strike>

```
return fr;
        ...
    ....
    ...

            }
```

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? `FragmentPagerAdapter` uses the tag itself, and so therefore you should not be trying to mess with that tag.

Comment: You did not answer my question. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a a Setting Fragment that contains button , when the user click that button a FragmentDialog is started now the result of the FragmentDailog should be returned to the setting dialog i use a listener that SettingFragment implements , and the FragmentDailog get the refrence using CustomLisenter mListener =(CustomListener) FragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("custom Tag");

Comment: actually the SettingFragment can show 10 different dialog so it implements 10 different listener

Comment: I have a a Setting Fragment that contains button , when the user click that button a FragmentDialog is started now the result of the FragmentDailog should be returned to the setting fragment i use a listener that SettingFragment implements , and the FragmentDailog get the refrence using CustomLisenter mListener =(CustomListener) FragmentManager.getFragmentByTag("custom Tag");

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are talking about. If you are lucky, somebody else will understand you and will be able to assist you.

Comment: @CommonsWare FWIW it doesn't look like FragmentPagerAdapter does use tags. getTag returns null for added fragments, suggesting it (should) be available for use elsewhere (were there a way to set the tag).

Comment: @dpk: The [source code to `FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v13/java/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java) shows them using the version of `add()` on `FragmentTransaction` that uses a tag.

Comment: @CommonsWare Derp, I see what happened. I had an error in my code. You're right, there's a tag. Damn.